# Sort multi level grouped Access report by ID

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a report grouped by 3 fields (field1, field2 & field3), I tried to sort it by record ID in different ways but failed.

Following is a simple example:

| ID | Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | AA | MM | Item1 |
| 2 | Z | AA | PP | Item2 |
| 3 | Z | BB | NN | Item3 |
| 4 | Z | BB | MM | Item4 |
| 5 | Z | AA | DD | Item5 |
| 6 | A | AA | CC | Item6 |
| 7 | A | BB | DD | Item7 |
| 8 | A | BB | MM | Item8 |
| 9 | A | BB | CC | Item9 |

Targeted Result:
I want the grouped items to be sorted by ID;

Sort of field1:

Because Group "Y" ID is 1, it must come first, then group "Z", then Group "A".

and so on for all groups.

Weeks ago I found a solution on a forum (don't remember where) but yesterday when I tested it, it had an error on sorting.

That solution was using a query to find the related ID to each group name then use these sorters (I called it Sorter1,2,3) to group the report (I merged it to the attached access example)

```
Sorter1: CInt(DMin("ID","[Master]","Field1='" & [Field1] & "'"))
Sorter2: CInt(DMin("ID","[Master]","Field2='" & [Field2] & "'"))
Sorter3: CInt(DMin("ID","[Master]","Field3='" & [Field3] & "'"))
```

It slows down the query for a large scale of data but gave perfect results except if an Item in field3 repeated in many other groups as shown in the picture.

[image: Sample Picture]

[Sample Access](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dsw96sR4CoeqbmJqjkedSJbnWr5l62ny/view?usp=sharing)
I think I need to limit the "Dmin" function for field3 to only those values with an ID greater than Sorter2 (I tried but failed).

Comment: Why are you even grouping if you don't put grouping data into respective group sections? Remove groupings and apply sort order in SortBy property or in Sorting & Grouping.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a report design, not code, issue. Requires download and review of file to analyze issue.

Comment: Actually, grouping in such report is required by these 3 levels, the original report is an engineering report grouped by Category, Class & Work Type. but I need the details of the report to be displayed in its ID sort, not as level 3 alphabetical sort.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by grouped items sorted by id.  What about Fields 2 & 3? 
 We need a picture of the desired result.  reading between the lines I'm starting to think you might be looking for a cross-tab.

Comment: If you want to group by these 3 levels then can't have an overall sort by ID. It does sort by ID within 3rd group. If you want ID sorted under field 1 then can't have grouping for fields 2 and 3. As @mazoula said, edit question to illustrate what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I already edited my question, explained exactly what is the targeted report and merge a solution I found with an error to the attached access file.

Comment: Still not making sense. If you want to sort by ID then NN record will list before MM.

Comment: I still don't understand, but to get the target report from the sample data sort by either ID or Field4 before sorting by Field3.  I'll put pictures up in the answer and cross my fingers this is right.

Answer (score 0):

it seems sort1 is used to order field1 by the lowest ID included in Field1 and so forth for sort2 and sort3.  At that point it seems that ordering by ID or Field4 comes before ordering by field3 so sort by id before sort3.

report record source:
[image]

Report Design:
[image]

Report Output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, "Field4" is not related to "ID" (I named it with the same ID to show that it is not sorted). "Field4" & subsequence fields can be any data on the real data table.

Comment: it may be far faster to convert the query and it's calculated fields into a table using a make table query.  Then run the solution filtering by ID rather than field4.

Comment: I found the solution for such delay, I created a query that contains only "Ser" & the fields to sort (sorter1,2,3) then linked it with the main query by "Ser"

Answer (score 0):

As I was thinking, I found that I've to limit Sorter2 & Sorter3 as following:

```
Sorter2: CInt(DMin("ID","[Master]","Field2='" & [Field2] & "'And ID >=" _
& DMin("ID","[Master]","Field1='" & [Field1] & "'")))

Sorter3: CInt(DMin("ID","[Master]",("Field3='" & [Field3] & "' And ID >=" _
& DMin("ID","[Master]","Field2='" & [Field2] & "'And ID >=" _
& DMin("ID","[Master]","Field1='" & [Field1] & "'")))))
```

Thanks for your assistant.